# Rest Export: Get rid of no result fields

Tags: views, 8

I have a rest export that exports various content types. However I am running into the problem of the export giving me empty no result attributes. Here is an example.

> {
>      "title": "Acme Porter Image",
>      "body": "",
>       "field_image": "http://192.241.172.112/sites/default/files/2016-02/beer-batter-is-better_1_2.jpg",
>       "field_videosour": ""
>     },
>     {
>       "title": "Acme Porter Description",
>       "body": "This thing has more hops than Michael Jordan. It is dark and has hints of chocolate",
>       "field_image": "",
>       "field_videosour": ""
>     },
>     {
>       "title": "Acme Porter Video Review",
>       "body": "",
>       "field_image": "",
>       "field_videosour": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCpLerLKD2k"
>     }

Does anyone know how to get rid of the no result elements from the response?

Thanks,
Emmanuel

Comment: Does the Hide If Empty option in views No Results Behavior configuration do anything?

Comment: Nope I have that on. If I put in a no result message in that field, that message gets put into the empty string. However I can't find how to just avoid that element entirely.

Comment: Probably a bug/feature request that should be reported.